# What's difference with these two in scala in print Set

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am learning Scala programming language, and got confused by this:

```
var set = Set("hello", "world")

set += "Tom"
println(set)

println(set += "Tom")
```

The first print will output

```
Set(hello, world, Tom)
```

But the second will output

```
()
```

So, why they are different, I thought `println(set += "Tom")` will first do, `set += "Tom"`, and then print its result? Isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala `a += b` dessugars to `a = a + b`. The type of assignment expression is Unit. So, unlike C or Java, the result of an assignment expression doesn't result in the left-hand side but in the Unit value.

Comment: thanks, that really help, I really got confused because this totally different from C..

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by @pedrofurla, the second print displays the result of evaluating the assignment, namely the `Unit` denoted with `()`.

In addition, note we can print the result of evaluating the following block delimited by curly brackets,

```
println( {set += "Tom" ; set} )
Set(hello, world, Tom)
```

namely, add `"Tom"` to `set` as the first expression, then deliver the updated `set` as the final result of the block evaluation.